# How can I solve this bearing question?

Tags: geometry

How do I answer this bearing question?
A boat is traveling from point O. It first goes to a point marked A is 20km on a bearing of 325 degrees then it travels from point A and goes to point B. B is on a bearing of 220 degrees and 19km from A.

[image]

I have tried putting this in a rectangle,l but I can’t find the angle at O. How can I?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is not very clear, what did you try to put in a rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hint : find x and then find y...........